# Iterate over values of object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to iterate over all values of a map.
I know it's possible to [iterate over all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object).
But is it possible to iterate directly over the values?

```
 var map = { key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' }
 for (var key in map) { ...} // iterates over keys
```

Comment: The question is so common, that I wonder that no one asked it before. But I can find no question like this on stackoverflow.

Comment: U iterate kvp's. Not just keys, u can access the keys values or both within an iteration. Map[key] would be the value of the iteration

Comment: @kcbeard - can you support your claim (*U iterate kvp's*) with some proofs / specification?

Comment: @amit why would u have keys and no access? There may not be a method to directly access them but u can iterate the keys and associated values and do it.therefore u are in actuality iterating both.

Comment: @kcbeard - That's simply wrong. You're only able to iterate keys, which allow you to access values - if you want to, but you can just as well not access the values at all (for example, if you want to list keys).

Comment: @amit I'm happy with being wrong but I wouldn't be iterating keys and values, without needing values. Since I see no reason to access a value from outside of its key I see the iteration as the iteration of the pair. Other wise it would not need a dictionary, it would be in array.

Comment: @amit I'm sure u can objects for a variety of uses. U can have empty values if u want. I'm sure iterating keys are applicable in the right situations. And I can be wrong all the time, but i am glad u can state that. But next time I need to iterate an object be it for need of access to keys or their associated values. It will be done the same way with the same syntax until a proven better way is shown to me. And which case I will be iterating values :)

Comment: Please rephrase the title to not misslead future readers.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r What is you suggestion for a title?

Comment: "Javascript: Iterate over values of an object". SO is virtually the most general reference for codes. E.g. I came here for a JS Map.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's not a map. It's simply an `Object`.

**Edit:** *below code is worse than OP's, as Amit pointed out in comments.*

You can "iterate over the values" by actually iterating over the *keys* with:

```
var value;
Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
    value = map[key];
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: @Matthias it may not seem this way at first, but it makes total sense when you consider one important point: the order of properties in an object is not enforced. e.g. if you say `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` and for loop or go through the `Object.keys`, you're actually not guaranteed to go 1, 2, 3, so a direct looping of values doesn't make as much sense. The `for ... in` (and Object.keys) is closer to a  loop that just says "while there are still properties left, get another property". `keys` gives you a place to enforce ordering, e.g. `Object.keys(myobj).sort().forEach(x => console.log(x)`

Comment: I don't see how this is any better then OP's `for(var key in map) {map[key]}`. It's longer, less readable, it wastes memory, it's execution is slower - is there any reason at all to do this?

Comment: I would also provide an actual `Map` usage example.

Answer (score 25):

I iterate like this and it works for me.

```
for (let [k, v] of myMap) {
    console.log("Key: " + k);
    console.log("Value: " + v);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I create `var myMap = { key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' }`, try use your code and get error: `TypeError: myMap is not iterable`. Only way for me is using `Object.entries(myMap)` as say @dmigo. Maybe you create map in other way?

Answer (score 11):

In the sense I think you intended, in ES5 or ES2015, no, not without some work on your part.

In ES2016, probably with `object.values`.

Mind you Arrays in JavaScript are effectively a map from an integer to a value, and the values in JavaScript arrays can be enumerated directly.

```
['foo', 'bar'].forEach(v => console.log(v)); // foo bar
```

Also, in ES2015, you can make an object iterable by placing a function on a property with the name of `Symbol.iterator`:

```
var obj = { 
    foo: '1', 
    bar: '2',
    bam: '3',
    bat: '4',
};

obj[Symbol.iterator] = iter.bind(null, obj);

function* iter(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        yield o[keys[i]];
    }
}

for(var v of obj) { console.log(v); } // '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

Also, per other answers, there are other built-ins that provide the functionality you want, like `Map` (but **not** `WeakMap` because it is not iterable) and `Set` for example (but these are not present in all browsers yet).

Answer (score 7):

EcmaScript 2017 introduced `Object.entries` that allows you to iterate over values and keys. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
var map = { key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' }

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

The result will be:

> key1: value1
>   key2: value2

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no direct method to do that with objects.

The [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type does have a [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) method that returns an iterator for the values

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to **deeply iterate** into a complex (nested) object for each **key & value**, you can do so using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
const iterate = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${obj[key]}`)

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone that comes across this, I managed to solve this in njs ( nginx js ) by doing the following:

```
>> var map = { key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2' }
>> for ( var i in map ){ console.log(i, map[i]) }
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [underscore.js and the each function](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

```
_.each({key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```